# Ghost icons in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, bug-reporting

When uninstalling applications there are cases in which the icon remains. I reinstall the same application and the icon is duplicated with the difference that the new one works and the old one doesn't. Where can I find the ghost icon?

Comment: The PRATAP link solved my problem, thank you very much