# 6 icons of oracale java are showing in my apps list

Tags: java, oracle

i installed java for android studio and after installing there are 6 icons of java app in app list, how can i remove this. i'm afraid that i might delete java. tell me a proper way
thanks

[image]

Comment: how did you install java

Comment: Why do you want "to remove this"?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1097435/739431 have a look

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078736/how-do-i-remove-extra-skype-icon-or-ghost-icons-for-removed-apps-from-gnome-shel

Comment: @Pilot6 coz it looks bizarre

Comment: I have them too. All of them are different apps.

Answer (score 1):

All these icons are different applications:

- Oracle Java 8 Console
- Oracle Java 8 Visual VM
- Oracle Java 8 Mission Control
- Oracle Java 8 Web Start
- Oracle Java 8 Policy Tool
- Oracle Java 8 Plugin Control Panel

All these programs are useful for Java development and there is no reason to "remove this".

If you really want to remove these Launcher items, you can delete `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applications`.

That won't remove JAVA itself.